# How to fuse an additional feature in training deep neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am training a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) to classify Spectrogram images (frequency over time). These Spectrograms were created from some signals on specific times, therefore the time of collection is also an important feature. How can I use this collection-time as a feature while training a CNN with Spectrogram images?

One thing that I guess would be possible, is to add it as an extra node in the last Dense layer, but I don't know which Keras functionality would allow me to do so.

Comment: take a look at this page, you can get multiple inputs and merge layers over time. tell me if you need a more detail explanation https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Comment: So I just need to define a new Input(shape=(1,)) and then concatenate the layers, right? And specify two inputs in model instantiation; Model([input1, input2], concatenation)? I'll give it a shot. Thanks (ευχαριστώ in case you're also Greek)

Comment: yes & yes & yes and no i'm not greek :) don't hesitate to ask again here, i've played myself with this not long ago.